# Node JS крашнул и выдал "javascript heap out of memory" ... <--- Last few GCs ---> ... <--- JS stacktrace ---> ... JavaScript memory fail

Tags: node.js, api, утечка-памяти, cheerio

Написал api на cheerio и спустя некоторое время выходит такая ошибка, иногда меняется название ошибки, но везде написано "javascript heap out of memory" и куча всего

Код node js: https://github.com/MuradImanYch/Website-LF-Backend/blob/master/app.js

[image: javascript heap out of memory]

Comment: У вас утечка памяти

Comment: В ваших функциях parsing() и liveParsing() допишите в конце return true; А если ваши массивы запихнуть в объект, то можно очень сильно уменьшить количество строк кода. app.get надо вынести из функции parsing() , т.к. она у вас запускается циклично